# SQL Command to find a string value that ends in 'Z

Tags: sql, command

I need to search a table to find Job Codes that end in 'Z'. What would the SQL command look like?

```
Select Job Code
From <table>
Where Job Code contains ????
```

Comment: `Where [Job Code] = 'Value'` for static value. to retrieve all value containing part of the string use `Where [Job Code] Like '%Value%'`. % is the wild chard character.

Answer (score 2):

Like will be what you need.  It allows you to do wildcard searches over a column.

```
Select [Job Code]
From <table>
Where [Job Code] like '%Z'
```

`%` is your wildcard, so `%Z` will find every job code that ends with Z

`%Z%` will find every job code that has Z in it, and `Z%` if you want it to start with Z

Depending on your platform `_` (underscore) can also be used as a wildcard for a single letter.  If you wanted to find only two character job codes that ended with z it would be `like '_Z'`